# linq group by statement not working

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I have a linq statement like following,

```
var v1 = from s in context.INFOONEs group s by s.DATET into xyz select xyz;
```

I am trying like following to display the results

```
foreach (var x in v1)
{
    Console.WriteLine(x.);
}
```

But intellisence is not showing the columns when I type x.

What I am doing wrong? And what is the right way to achieve what I am trying to accomplish?

Thanks

Comment: Can you remember the columns from memory? Perhaps intellisense is acting up, happens to me all the time. Usually restarting VS sorts it out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

because there is no column in x. There are some record(s) under each group.So you need to get those records:

```
foreach (var x in v1)
{
    Console.WriteLine(x.Key); // display the Key of current group
    foreach(var item in x) // iterate over the records in the group
    {
       Console.WriteLine(item.) // here you can access your columns
    }
}
```

Comment: can u please explain why there are two loops. What's going on? Thanks

Comment: @xyz in the first loop you are iterating over the groups, since a group can have more than one item you need a second loop.

Comment: thanks a lot, can you refer me to easy and helpful tutorial related to linq.